# How to enable lazy search by default CirrusSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mediawiki, fuzzy-search, mediawiki-extensions, elastica

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of a search with a "tilde" as the default suffix in CirrusSearch on MediaWiki.

I have a wiki with an article containing the word "connection" several times.

Currently, when I do a fuzzy search, for example with "connexion" or "connectio", I get no search results.

If, on the other hand, I do a fuzzy search, with "connexion~" or "connectio~" for example, I get "connection" as the result for my search.

Is there a way of ensuring that all searches are analysed by CirrusSearch as if they had a "tilde" at the end?

I've tested lots of different configurations in `LocalSettings.php`, but unfortunately I haven't found one that solves my problem.